# Gitlab block user for a mistake in ldap dn for case sensitive diferences

Tags: authentication, ldap, gitlab

Im trying to conect gitlab with ldap to centralize my authentication.

Im having a problem when i try to log in because gitlab blocks the users.

The base_dn where the users are is ou=People,dc=dominio,dc=com
When i try to log in all works fine until Gitlab make a sync and block the user because on the gitlab database the base_dn is saved in lowcase.

LDAP account "uid=user1,ou=people,dc=dominio,dc=com" does not exist anymore, blocking GitLab user "Usuario" (user1@dominio.com)

Gitlab is able to read all the info from the user in theLDAP and also create the user on the gitlab system(full name, email, etc).

User "Usuario" (user1@dominio.com) was created
But later block the user and im not able to log in, every time i unblock manually, the gitlab block again.

Here all the process:

User "Usuario" (user1@dominio.com) was created
(LDAP) saving user user1@dominio.com from login with admin => false, extern_uid => uid=user1,ou=people,dc=dominio,dc=com
LDAP account "uid=user1,ou=people,dc=dominio,dc=com" does not exist anymore, blocking GitLab user "Usuario" (user1@dominio.com)

When i check in the user profile they show this info:
LDAP uid: uid=user1,ou=people,dc=dominio,dc=com

In the LDAP the real path is:
uid=user1,ou=People,dc=dominio,dc=com

Some idea how i said to gitlab rescpect the upercase or not be case sensitive?

Comment: Why? LDAP isn't case-sensitive. It doesn't care. Why should you?

Answer (score 1):

LDAP itself is case-insensitive, so in queries against LDAP it doesn't matter. GitLab tries to normalize all DNs to lowercase before comparing values on its side since GitLab itself is case-sensitive.

With that in mind, I'm not clear where you're running into problems. It sounds like it's probably a bug if it really is related to the case. It's also possible there's another issue causing the user sync to block your user(s).

If you have clear reproduction steps the best bet is probably to create an issue at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues. Tag the issue with `~ldap` and ping me (@dblessing). Happy to try to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution.

the **user_filter:** i used have some issue, dont support omniauth-ldap's custom filter syntax.

I was using

```
user_filter: '(&(objectclass=*)(memberof=cn=gitlab,ou=Groups,dc=dominio,dc=com)(uid=%{username}))'
```

But i change for somnething simple as:

```
user_filter: '(memberof=cn=infra_gitlab,ou=Groups,dc=dominio,dc=com)'
```

And start to works...

Comment: There is nothing case-sensitive about this.

Comment: Same problem, but i do not use any user filter. The user is created correctly but its state is "ldap_blocked" and no login is allowed.